# How to write asc and in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote  this query but did not work there is problem in writing `asc and` follow each other .

How I can solve this problem ?

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM coe_courses LEFT JOIN equal_coe ON
 equal_coe.course_number=coe_courses.course_number 
LEFT JOIN student_record ON coe_courses.course_number=
student_record.course_number order by student_record.course_number asc AND student_record.id=". $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Comment: You're missing a `WHERE` clause and make sure you started the session.

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...

Comment: `order by ... and`? Your query syntax is messed up. You **CAN** have that kind of statement in your `order by`, but it's not going to work like you think it will.

Comment: `student_record.id=". $_SESSION['user_id']` ... tl;dr: PDO. PDO. PDO. PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query needs to be rearranged to use a `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM coe_courses 
      LEFT JOIN equal_coe ON equal_coe.course_number=coe_courses.course_number 
      LEFT JOIN student_record ON coe_courses.course_number=student_record.course_number 
      WHERE student_record.id=". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."
      order by student_record.course_number asc";
```